# List all named items in each xml node

Tags: xml, asp-classic, xml-parsing

I'm once again having problems pulling info from XML files in classic asp.

I have this xml file: http://treci.co.uk/members/temp/test_corp_2.xml

and I am using this code to pull all the node names and values:

```
kill_url = "http://treci.co.uk/members/temp/test_corp_2.xml"

Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Set xh = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xh.open "GET", kill_url, False
xh.send
xml = xh.responseText
oXML.LoadXML xml

set nodes = oXML.selectNodes("//*")    
for i = 0 to nodes.length -1
    response.write(nodes(i).nodeName & " - " & nodes(i).text & "<br />")
next
```

but this is not pulling all the nameditems within each node.  Is there a way to do this and produce a result like this:

```
name="kills"  
key="killID"  
columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID"  
killID="33891411"  
solarSystemID="31002317"  
killTime="2013-10-18 10:00:00"  
moonID="0"  
characterID="92217137"  
characterName="Justin Perelta"  
corporationID="1160301547"
```

etc etc

basically going through every named item in each node and listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid my VB*x* skills have long since evaporated but you are selecting all of the elements in the XML document (`selectNodes(//*)`) and wondering why you don't get the attribute names and values. Your code loops over the elements, not the attributes of the elements.

Also, you need to reference the nodes via `nodes.item(i)` rather than `nodes(i)`. That is `nodes` isn't normally an array in the DOM.

You need an inner loop which iterates over the map returned by the `attributes`property of each node.

Something on the lines of:

```
set nodes = oXML.selectNodes("//*")    
for i = 0 to nodes.length -1
    set attributes = nodes.item(i).attributes
    for j = 0 to attributes.length - 1
        response.write(attributes.item(j).nodeName & " - " & attributes.item(j).value & "<br />")
    next
next
```

Comment: thats sorted my problem, thank you very much.  Well apart from attributes.item(i).value  which I changed to attributes.item(j).value

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. Fixed it for the record.